# Is there a way to just fix indentation, not do full formatting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Coming from eclipse, I'm used to being able to paste C++ code in and do ctrl-i (I think that was the shortcut) to just touch up the indentation.  On vscode, I got "format document" working, and the results are fine, but it's very heavy handed.  The issue is that in a collaborative environment with revision control, it makes a huge number of "changes" that confuse everyone and make it hard to track real changes.   I know people may have opinions on this problem, but the real questions is, does vscode have a way to just fix the indentations for a section without going after spacing, location of line breaks, and all the rest?

Comment: I don't use VSCode.  Can you highlight just the code block that you desire to reformat, and then do the format command?

Comment: `The issue is that in a collaborative environment with revision control, it makes a huge number of "changes" that confuse everyone`  that's why you should define a coding style, that should be used by everyone. Such a style could be forced/automated by using e.g. `clang-format` and can be configured using its config file.

Comment: @t.niese • My team is in the process of doing *exactly* that!  It's not easy to get to that point, though.  One of the developers has a side-project to retain history, so the "blame" line is useful rather than just tagging the poor soul that did the reformating.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if everyone got on board, but we don't have that kind of culture here.  People use all different tools, including many vi and gedit people.